# Solder mask expansion issue in altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Can anyone tell me if this is ok and it is just a drawing issue or I have a real problem when ordering my pcbs?

[image: solder mask.png]

My understanding of solder mask expansion is the minimum distance between a track/pad... and the next one (Isn't it?) So, I wanted to have avery wide track and put instead of a small distance to the next one, a bigger one. But I see the bone white line inside of the copper track...

How can I make this distance bigger? I want to create a gnd plane and the distance seems to small for me (Big track is AC current)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soldermask Expansion defines the clearance of Solder Mask to Copper. If you want Copper to Copper clearance, you need to set up a Clearance rule.

The "bone white" that you see is your PCB. The outer gold is probably your ground plane. Just go to Design Rules dialog and change the Electrical > Clearance rule.